# Places to ask about wireless technologies and networks

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask about wireless/network technologies (such as LTE, WCDMA, TCP/IP, IMS ...)? Should we make a new site for that?

I want to discuss network technologies itself (such as protocols, designs, optimization ...) not admin or programming topics.

Let me make sample question:

- How to remove IP fragmentation from LTE core network because of GTP overhead?
- What is the maximum throughput of WCDMA with HSPA+?
- How to reduce LTE UE battery consumption? such as DRX and inactivity timers, any other option?
- ...

Comment: Superuser is the closest match, but without knowing what your question is, there's no way to tell for certain.

Comment: What's your sample question?

Comment: It depends on how the questions relate to them.  By the sound of it, Super User might be appropriate for at least certain types of questions on this topic.  Server Fault might apply if you're doing professional level configuration of such devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Network Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52519/network-engineering?referrer=_nsuQsHYjSiGFjXXhw75VA2) proposal on Area51 is a good option especially for the IP related examples you presented, but I don't want the [Telecommunications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40212/telecommunications?referrer=gmPr_n4_vstYR3L0CfC-5Q2) proposal to be ignored either.  Many of the concepts you are asking about, especially related to LTE, and UMTS/W-CDMA, are very much on topic per the example questions.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your usage of the technology.

If you are an end user and need configuration assistance for instance then [Super User](http://superuser.com) might fit your needs.

If you are a company administrator setting up a huge network then try [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

If you want to program using such technology and are stuck with a specific programming task then [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is the right place.

And if you like help shaping a future site for Network-Engineering then have a look at the [Area51 proposal for Network-Engineering](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52519/network-engineering).

Comment: Might want to add http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52519/network-engineering which is in its commitment phase! (Does depend of the question though)

Comment: In fact, not all about these. I want to discuss network technologies itself such as protocols, optimization of network arch. and physical layer issues (such as interference, MAC layer issue ...) I can't see any good place to discuss network technologies itself. thanks

Comment: Do you want to discuss it in theory or with a real life task in mind?

Comment: I think real life task + specification discussion. Most of engineers who worked in mobile devices company (such as SEC, LG, Apple, Qualcomm ...), and network equipment vendors are facing real life issues because of miss understanding of sophisticated specifications. And just try to Googling spits out too many information.